# Could not find ring-cors:ring-cors:0.1.5

Tags: java, gradle, apache-storm

I just upgraded apache storm version from `1.0.2` to `1.2.2` and since then my build is failing.

**build.gradle -**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.storm:storm-core:1.2.2', {
       ext { fatJarExclude = true }
   }
 ...
}
```

**Error -**

```
> Task :service:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration 
':service:compileClasspath'.
> Could not find ring-cors:ring-cors:0.1.5.
Required by:
  project :service > project :indexer > org.apache.storm:storm-core:1.2.2
```

I added [ring-cors](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ring-cors/ring-cors/0.1.5) dependency too but it's still failing.

```
compile group: 'ring-cors', name: 'ring-cors', version: '0.1.5'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ring-cors` ( https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ring-cors/ring-cors [check the Repository section in the table])  requires `Clojars` repository dependency in your `build.gradle`.

```
repositories {
  maven {url 'http://clojars.org/repo/'}
}
```

Hope this fixes your problem.